# Add clipboard event sounds

Tags: xorg, clipboard, sound-theme

How can I add sound when system clipboard is updated? I use xclip under tmux, but other apps probably don't. Which interface should I use? Ideally this should work on all window managers (unless there is good reason against that idea).

Comment: There is a script thing you could use talked about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685999/trigger-an-event-when-clipboard-content-changes) - you could use `aplay` or `paplay` to play the audio file.

Comment: @wilf thanks, but this script implements busy waiting anti-pattern, there has to be a better way